# Portiacrawl delivers no information

Tags: scrapy, portia

I have a small Problem with portia/scrapy and maybe somebody have a idea what is going wrong.
I actually working with portia 16.02 in a vagrant enviroment (on windows 10). I create a spider for a small private project.
The spider checks an resultspage (as start page) for an flightroute between OSL (Oslo) and LAX (Los Angeles) on a special date on expedia.de (heavy js...).
I annotate the site and the sample looks great (i added another startpage and the sample looks also fine). So i tried in the virtual machine an portiacrawl to check the export:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/crawler.py:115: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: SPIDER_MANAGER_CLASS option is deprecated. Please use SPIDER_LOADER_CLASS.
  self.spider_loader = _get_spider_loader(settings)
2016-02-26 14:12:10 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.0.0 started (bot: scrapybot)
2016-02-26 14:12:10 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2016-02-26 14:12:10 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'FEED_FORMAT': 'xml', 'FEED_URI': 'test.xml', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapyjs.SplashAwareDupeFilter'}
2016-02-26 14:12:10 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: CloseSpider, FeedExporter, TelnetConsole, LogStats, CoreStats, SpiderState
2016-02-26 14:12:13 [py.warnings] WARNING: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyjs/middleware.py:8: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.log` has been deprecated, Scrapy now relies on the builtin Python library for logging. Read the updated logging entry in the documentation to learn more.
  from scrapy import log

2016-02-26 14:12:13 [py.warnings] WARNING: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyjs/dupefilter.py:8: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.dupefilter` is deprecated, use `scrapy.dupefilters` instead
  from scrapy.dupefilter import RFPDupeFilter

2016-02-26 14:12:13 [py.warnings] WARNING: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapyjs/cache.py:11: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.contrib.httpcache` is deprecated, use `scrapy.extensions.httpcache` instead
  from scrapy.contrib.httpcache import FilesystemCacheStorage

2016-02-26 14:12:13 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, PageActionsMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, SlybotJsMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2016-02-26 14:12:13 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2016-02-26 14:12:13 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: DupeFilterPipeline
2016-02-26 14:12:13 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-02-26 14:12:13 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-02-26 14:12:13 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-02-26 14:12:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.expedia.de/Flight-SearchResults?inpPackageType=FLIGHT_ONLY&inpInfants=2&inpFlightClass=2&inpDepartureDates=17.03.2016&inpDepartureDates=24.03.2016&inpDepartureTimes=362&inpDepartureTimes=362&inpFlightRouteType=3&inpHotelRoomCount=1&inpFlightAirlinePreference=&inpAdultCounts=1&inpIsNonstopOnly=N&intcp=0&inpChildCounts=0&action=FlightSearchResults%40searchFlights&inpSeniorCounts=0&inpRefundableFlightsOnly=N&inpSortType=0&inpDepartureLocations=Oslo%2C+Norwegen+(OSL-Alle+Flugh%C3%A4fen)&inpDepartureLoc&inttkn=NfXCUxEImb3egksh> from <GET https://goo.gl/6u5fEm>
2016-02-26 14:12:14 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.expedia.de/Flight-SearchResults?inpPackageType=FLIGHT_ONLY&inpInfants=2&inpFlightClass=2&inpDepartureDates=17.03.2016&inpDepartureDates=24.03.2016&inpDepartureTimes=362&inpDepartureTimes=362&inpFlightRouteType=3&inpHotelRoomCount=1&inpFlightAirlinePreference=&inpAdultCounts=1&inpIsNonstopOnly=N&intcp=0&inpChildCounts=0&action=FlightSearchResults%40searchFlights&inpSeniorCounts=0&inpRefundableFlightsOnly=N&inpSortType=0&inpDepartureLocations=Oslo%2C+Norwegen+(OSL-Alle+Flugh%C3%A4fen)&inpDepartureLoc&inttkn=NfXCUxEImb3egksh> (referer: None)
2016-02-26 14:12:15 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.expedia.de/Flight-SearchResults?inpPackageType=FLIGHT_ONLY&inpInfants=2&inpFlightClass=2&inpDepartureDates=17.03.2016&inpDepartureDates=24.03.2016&inpDepartureTimes=362&inpDepartureTimes=362&inpFlightRouteType=3&inpHotelRoomCount=1&inpFlightAirlinePreference=&inpAdultCounts=1&inpIsNonstopOnly=N&intcp=0&inpChildCounts=0&action=FlightSearchResults%40searchFlights&inpSeniorCounts=0&inpRefundableFlightsOnly=N&inpSortType=0&inpDepartureLocations=Oslo%2C+Norwegen+%28OSL-Alle+Flugh%C3%A4fen%29&inpDepartureLocations=Los+Angeles%2C+CA%2C+USA+%28LAX-Los+Angeles+Intl.%29&inpArrivalLocations=Los+Angeles%2C+CA%2C+USA+%28LAX-Los+Angeles+Intl.%29&inpArrivalLocations=Oslo%2C+Norwegen+%28OSL-Alle+Flugh%C3%A4fen%29&inttkn=mrRyD4CXEnw3zhjf> (referer: None)
2016-02-26 14:12:15 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-02-26 14:12:15 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1869,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 118471,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 26, 14, 12, 15, 963588),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'log_count/WARNING': 3,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 2, 26, 14, 12, 13, 657551)}
```

Some warnings okay, after that i checked the exportfile but the export file is empty. I tested again with a specified xml files as output file but these file is also empty.
Anybody an idea why i get no export?

Thanks!

Regards
Timo

Comment: I don't see items scraped from the end stats. You should see something like `'item_scraped_count': SOMENUMBER,`

Comment: Hi Paul, no the count is Zero. i checked my anotiation test and the test is fine, portia anotate correctly all Things and extracted them. I added the sample page as start page to the Spider but get no extracted back.

Comment: I think i found the Problem. It looks that portia differs between annotate and scraping. I activate the JS in the Portia Webinterface. But it looks like that i had to activate splash locally in the vagrant vm